# Accessing a variable from the main function in a C file from an Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, c

Not sure if this is even possible since I don't have much experience with either language but if I have a file driver.c and with in it have something like this

```
char *getData(int user){
    unsigned char *buffer = malloc(2800);

    // ... do all the stuff

    return buffer;
 }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
   int user = 1;

   unsigned char *buffer = getData(user);

   return 0;
}
```

Would I be able to access the buffer variable that is created with in the `main()` function from another file/class that is written in Objective-C?

Comment: @Merlevede so if with in the driver.h file I set "extern usigned char *buffer;" Then I would be able to access it from any other file in the application since this would be making it global?

Comment: Can you create a shared memory space, such as a file?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Not quite sure what you mean actually.

Comment: So, since this was immediately closed as a duplicate, apparently, the only way to share data between a class and a function is to use global variables? Funny, because I'd have thought passing it as a parameter in a method might have worked too (assuming he renames `driver.c` to `driver.m`)...

Comment: @NSGod I'm fine changing the file type to .m What In the end I'm trying to achieve here is just making this code that I wrote in C http://pastebin.com/ufbvziUR return a buffer that can be consumed by another part of the app.